# symmetricDS two way ssl handshake(clientAuth=false)

Tags: ssl, https, keystore, tomcat8, symmetricds

**Problem summary:**
I am trying to run symmetric ds on tomcat with ssl. Setup details
1). MasterNode M1: running on tomcat.
2). Cleint node C1: running on tomcat.
I am able to run symmetricds on tomcat without ssl. This setup works fine all sync happens.
Now when I am trying to run tomcat with following setting for ssl, it gives bad_certificate error on client node:
connection setting on Master node:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="10"
algorithm="PKIX" allowTrace="false" 
ciphers=""
clientAuth="true"
enableLookups="true"
keystoreFile="/root/symmetric-server-3.8.28/security/keystore.p12"
keystorePass="changeit@1"
keystoreType="pkcs12"
port="31415"
redirectPort="-1"
scheme="https"
secure="true"
sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"
sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"
truststoreFile="/root/symmetric-server-3.8.28/security/keystore.p12"
truststorePass="changeit@1"
truststoreType="pkcs12"/>
```

connector setting on Client node:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="10"
algorithm="PKIX" allowTrace="false" 
ciphers=""
clientAuth="true"
enableLookups="true"
keystoreFile="/root/symmetric-server-3.8.28/security/keystore2.p12"
keystorePass="changeit@1"
keystoreType="pkcs12"
port="31415"
redirectPort="-1"
scheme="https"
secure="true"
sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"
sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"
truststoreFile="/root/symmetric-server-3.8.28/security/keystore2.p12"
truststorePass="changeit@1"
truststoreType="pkcs12"/>
```

Note: If I run Master node tomcat with clientAuth=false then everything works fine. On further debugging I found that client is not providing its certificate during TLS handshake. Following is error: Experts please help what config I need to do so that client provide certificate:

**Error:**
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate

Comment: Have the certificates been exchanged between master and client node keystores?

Comment: During TLS handshake server is presenting its certificate but client node is not presenting its certificate. On server side ssl logs says: null cert chain. 
http-nio-31415-exec-8, fatal error: 42: null cert chain
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
%% Invalidated:  [Session-4, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384]
http-nio-31415-exec-8, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = bad_certificate
http-nio-31415-exec-8, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain

Comment: has the certificate been added to client's keystore?

Comment: yes i have added client certificates in client's keystore and cross checked. I think I am not able figure out where to provide keystore on client node. Is keystore path provided in tomcat is sufficient or need to provide it somewhere else?

Comment: Should be enough. Have the certificates been exchanged between master and client?

Comment: It worked for me on 3.9.28. I explicitly provided keystore path and keystore password in JAVA_OPTS for tomcat in catalina.sh:  export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystore_file path -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystore_password"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to SymmetricDS 3.8.31.  There was an issue that was fixed that allows for client TLS authentication now:

http://www.symmetricds.org/issues/view.php?id=2886

Comment: My issue got resolved on 3.8.28 as well. I am planning to upgrade my SymmetricDS to 3.8.31. I will update you if it worked fine.